# How to store wishlist product on server side using api (Magento + Vue)?

Tags: vue.js, magento, vue-component, vuex

I am currently using vsf + magento , meanwhile wishlist items are stored in cookie , but its not that good to store wishlist items in cookie.

Is their any way , using api we can store wishlist items on server side ?

Answers appriciated

Answer (score -1):

1.Copy all content of this url insaid you custom module

```
/Custom/Module/view/frontend/web/js/vue.js
```

2.Configure requirejs-config.js

```
    /Custom/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

var config = {
   map: {
       '*': {
           vue: 'Custom_Module/js/vue'>             
       }
   } };
```

3.And to use it:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'vue'
], function ($, Vue) {
    "use strict";
    // code...
});
```

Comment: He didn't use Magento as frontend app, but VSF.